# How do I create an object in windows forms through code?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a label through my code in windows forms. How do I do that?

Comment: Just create the object and set the properties you want and add it to wherever you want it to be seen

Comment: But how do I do that through code though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance of `Label` class codebehind

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
...

Label label = new Label();

//Now, you can assign values to the label properties

label.Text = "Welcome to Stackoverflow";

...

//Add this label to the form
this.Controls.Add(label);
```

MSDN documentation : [Label class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label?view=netcore-3.1#examples)